# How can I space three buttons, text to the left and a button to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have tried some different ideas. First I put the three buttons with float left and the one with float right. I also added the following for the text. But the text is not aligned.

```
<div style="
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
">194 rows retrieved - 194 displayed</div>
```

When I look at the DIV the text inside is still at the top. Can someone explain how I can get the text to go in the middle so there's an equal space above and below the text?

What I really need is some way to do this:

```
 button  button  button  sometexthere                                           button
```

Here's a fiddle I created http://jsfiddle.net/M4xTe/  The problem with this is I would like the buttons and text to be grouped on the left and the other button to be floating right. Currently they are all spaced equally.

Comment: can you create fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it with `display: table-cell` instead off `display: inline-block`

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rmyt/)

Comment: I tried that but it goes below the buttons that are marked float-left

Comment: If possible can you show me how I could do this with buttons on the left and right also? I tried this but could not seem to get the fiddle right.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `inline-block` and replace only with the `inline`. The `inline` property of the div will make the text algin center.

The below code should work fine:

`<button>hello</button> <button>world</button> <div style="
    display: inline;
    height: 40px;
    text-align:center;
">194 rows retrieved - 194 displayed</div>`

Answer (score 0):

[Demo for this](http://jsfiddle.net/k3rnel31/3PVbV/)

```
.div{
height: 40px;
display:inline-block;
padding:10px 10px;
list-style:none;
}



<div class="div">number 1</div>
<div class="div">number 2</div>
<div class="div">number 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use two containers which are floated left/right.

```
<div>
    <div class="leftGroup">
        <button>Left 1</button>
        <button>Left 2</button>
        <button>Left 3</button>
        <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rightGroup">
        <button>Right</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.leftGroup {
    float: left;
}

.rightGroup {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8sTWy/